# Is clearing application cache, it's deleted "data/data/<package_name>/files" files?

Tags: android, caching

Is "data/data//files" deleted when application cache cleared in android from setting page?

Comment: Did you give it a try instead?

Comment: Yes everything will be cleared... i.e. DB, Prefs, Files

Comment: My problem is out of it: I am saving a text file in this directory, but some time, application clear the cache (as I have read from android developer's site when it needs more memory) and it also clean my saved file. What should be the better alternative to keep my file till application exist. Saving details on server/through internet not a good idea for me.

Comment: depending on how big your saved data is, you may consider sharedPreferences

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm having same situation when users complain a lot about settings they've lost which I keep in /files folder. For some of them it happens every 2-3 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/data/data/<packagename>/files` folder you get e.g. via [Context#getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) is not cleared when the cache is cleared.

The files here will only be deleted when your app is uninstalled or the user hits the delete data button in system settings.

The `/data/data/<packagename>/cache` folder [Context#getCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) on the other hand can be cleared automatically. (or through the clear cache button in system settings)

As the documentation states

> These files will be ones that get deleted first when the device runs low on storage. There is no guarantee when these files will be deleted.

Comment: Yes, that's I know, but I am facing this problem, when I put application in background (by pressing home button), some time (very often) it's close the application and also clear the application cache automatically. I am saving data in "data/data/application context/file". What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Data in ../files should not get deleted automatically. Maybe you did not save the files before the crash or you have an error in reading the files?

Comment: When saving this file, if it success then I allow the app to go next, so it's not the case to saving file, Also reading files didn't give the error and read successfully.
Could you please suggest me a better alternative to doing this implementaion?

Comment: Sounds good as it is. I don't know why you loose your data then :( Maybe you can find the reason for the dataloss if you have a look at logcat between crash and restart. Or check the content of the directory from commandline (`adb shell run-as <packagename>` then `ls files` could work)