# file contents are getting erased in /data/data/package/files folder in android java

Tags: java, android

From my apk i am writting some contents to /data/data/package/files/settings.data files, when i reboot the system file is still exists but contents in the file are empty.

Can somebody help me .

Answer (score 0):

Check that your application always closes the files before it exits, even if it exits due to an exception.  The recommended Java idiom is this:

```
  OutputStream os = // open it.
  try {
      // write stuff to os
  } finally {
      try {
          os.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          // log error ... file not written completely
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be happened only when you are not closing Streams. And `../files` directory can not be deleted automatically.

[This link may help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509762/is-clearing-application-cache-its-deleted-data-data-package-name-files-fil)